# Activate `pipewire` to use bluetooth headset properly

Tags: bluetooth, audio

I was searching for a solution on how to use a bluetooh headset on elementary OS without reverting to bad audio quality and stumbled upon this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1338934/676709

I tried to follow the instructions to install and setup `pipewire` which were mentioned in the answer (https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire).

Unfortunately, I could not run

```
# cp /usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.* /etc/systemd/user/
```

because the directory `/usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/systemd` does not exist.

**So I wonder if there is there another possibility to activate `pipewire` on elementary OS in order to ultimately use my bluetooth headset properly?**